Catan longest road
If player1 holds longest road card (for example 7 pieces), if player2 reaches 7 pieces, both now having 7p long road, does player1 keep the longest road card until player2 reaches 8p road or does the card go to bank because of a tie?

According to the FAQ, player1 keeps the card until another player builds a longer road:

Longest Road - What happens if a player builds a continuous road that has the same length as the road belonging to the owner of the Longest Road card?
The card stays with its current owner.

Also note that the card text explicitly states that player2 needs to build a longer road, not a road of the same length as player1's:

Another player who builds a longer road takes this card.


Yes, also recall that player2 might be able to shorten player1's road, if they can manage to build a (legal) settlement in the middle of it

Indeed.  It is theoretically possible that... say... player 1 has a length 10 road, player 2 has a length 7 road and player 3 has a length 6 road... and player 2 places a knight or builds a settlement in the middle of player 1's roads, thereby cutting it into two length 5 roads.  In such a situation the longest road card would have passed to the new road leader player 2, but if instead player 3 also had 7 roads at the time there is not an individual road leader and so it returns to the box until such a time as there is a single player with the most roads (at least 5).
